# Rails 5 ActiveRecord Query - Possible to join 3 tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Given the following models:

```
User: id
UserPosition: user_id, job_title_id
JobTitle: id | title
```

With Rails 5, how can I do something like:

```
current_user.job_title
```

What would I need to lookup `UserPosition` and then `JobTitle` to get the `title`?

Is this possible with one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this through associations like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_positions
  has_many :job_titles, through: :user_positions
end

class UserPositions < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :job_title
end

class JobTitle < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_positions
  has_many :users, through: :user_positions
end
```

Here's [the documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) for a many to many relationship in Rails.

Answer (score 1):

With your relationships defined as:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_positions
end

class JobTitle < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_positions
end

class UserPosition < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :job_title
end
```

Then you can use `joins`, with both models `job_title` and `user_position`, through the `user` model, and knowing the `user.id`, so, then you can use  `pluck` to get the needed attribute:

```
User.joins(user_positions: :job_title).where(id: 1).pluck('job_titles.title')
```

Which would give you an SQL query like:

```
SELECT job_titles.title 
FROM "users" 
INNER JOIN "user_positions" 
ON "user_positions"."user_id" = "users"."id" 
INNER JOIN "job_titles" 
ON "job_titles"."id" = "user_positions"."job_title_id" 
WHERE (users.id = 1)
```